# How can you merge two objects into a single object including methods

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, decorator

I want to merge multiple objects into a single object including methods using ES6 syntax. I have a fiddle here: http://www.es6fiddle.net/isvfozdu/ that shows what I'm trying to accomplish (code below as well).

I've toyed around with decorator patterns that look like they should work but ultimately don't.

The problem I'm trying to solve is a single object that has different functionality depending on its attributes, and having all of the functionality is potentially harmful.

Thanks!

```
class A {
  hi(){
    console.log('hi');
  }
}

class B {
  bye(){
    console.log('bye');
  }
}

class C {
  hello(){
    console.log('hello');
  }
}

// x = A & B, not C

x.hi();
x.bye();
x instanceof A // true
x instanceof B // true
x instanceof C // false

// y = A & C, not B

y.h1();
y.hello();
y instanceof A // true
y instanceof B // false
y instanceof C // true
```

The idea here is to add the functionality of one class to another depending on the properties of an instance of A.

```
let a = new A();

if(a.isEnabled){
    let b = new B();
    magicFunctionOrSomething(a, b);
}

a.bye();
```

Comment: You need to include the relevant code **in the question itself**.

Comment: Changed. Thanks Amit

Comment: Good. Now can you demonstrate the use case?

Comment: Do you just need `B extends A`?

Comment: No, sub classing won't work.

Answer (score -2):

As I understand you need prototype chaining. See MDN explanation by the link. The first example of the usage is simple and may help you.
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf)